# How to ensure that the complete data from web services is downloaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api

I'm currently building a phone-Gap android application. Is there any way to ensure that the complete data from the web services is downloaded when doing AJAX calls.
In case of any network issues what can be done to resume the download rather than starting from the beginning.
This is a generic question and I'm looking forward for ideas.
The Data from web service is in JSON

Answer (score 0):

Hey these all callback functions in ajax process which handle different aspects of process:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: 'url',
    type: 'GET',
    async: false,
    beforeSend: function(){
        console.log('before')
    },
    complete: function() {
        console.log('completed')
    },
    success:function(data){console.log('success')

    },error:function(err){
        console.error(err.message || 'Something went wrong')
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.